# Update .NET Core Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2019, preview, dotnet-tool

I'm trying to use EntityFrameworkCore@3.1. In order to do this at this point I already have:
- Installed Visual Studio 2019 Preview
- Installed the .NET Core 3.1 Runtime
- Installed the .NET Core 3.1 SDK

Now I still can't run the command `dotnet ef migrations add xxx`. It's saying that I have to update the dotnet tools. So I run the following command in an administrator powershell:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
Tool 'dotnet-ef' was reinstalled with the latest stable version (version '3.0.0')
```

Okay, not including the preview versions. So I try to specify the version explicitly:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version="3.1.0-preview1.19506.2"
error NU1202: Package dotnet-ef 3.1.0-preview1.19506.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any. Package dotnet-ef 3.1.0-preview1.19506.2 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1)
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to update due to the following:
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Now it's saying that a .NET Core 3.1 tool is not compatible with the .NET Core 3.1 runtime.

However, if I do a simple version check:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dotnet --version
3.1.100-preview1-014459
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dotnet ef --version
Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools
3.0.0
```

I can see that the EntityFrameworkCore.Tools is still at version 3.0.0 instead of 3.1.0 (which tools version is installed in my project).

Am I still missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: do you have 16.4 preview 2 installed?

Comment: My version is 16.4.0 Preview 2.0

Comment: I tried to install everything on a new Windows installation on another laptop and I immediately chose .NET Core 3.1, no other .NET Core frameworks. Now when I run `dotnet --version` I also get `3.1.100-preview1-014459` and `dotnet ef --version` gives me `3.1.0` as well. But now dotnet ef complains about the fact that I use .NETCore3.1 and tells that it's only compatible with .NETCore3.1. Probably a bug.

Comment: could be. report it to Microsoft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @lars-haupt-hansen for pointing me to the bug, I [followed](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/12963) the [trail](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18587) to the [PR](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/18595) which shows it was merged into "aspnet:release/3.1". <s>The latest 3.1 is still a [preview](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/releases) (preview3)</s> [edit: it's out of preview]. You can find and download the latest SDK [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

To use it in Visual Studio projects, you have to

1. install the SDK from the above link;
2. go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and enable "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK"; *(not required for 3.1 anymore)*
3. restart VS *(not required for 3.1 anymore)*
4. Go to each project properties, and then you can choose the Target Framework `.NET Core 3.1`

Then to install EF Core via the command line, run `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef` from your project directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-preview4.19216.3

dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-preview8.19405.11
```

Comment: I doubt that this solves the problem or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.