# Facing Issue while Installing dotnet-ef with netcoreapp3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, netcoreapp3.0

I am trying to use EF core Migration features. But when I install dotnet-ef tools from NuGet, below error message is thrown.  My app version is netcoreapp3.0.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.0-preview3.19554.8
```

> error NU1202: Package dotnet-ef 3.1.0-preview3.19554.8 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0) / any. Package dotnet-ef 3.1.0-preview3.19554.8 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any

Older version only support netcoreapp2.1

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.1
```

> error NU1202: Package dotnet-ef 3.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0) / any. Package dotnet-ef 3.0.1 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)

Actually which dotnet-ef version is supporting netcoreapp3.0 Any idea?

Answer (score 13):

This works for me on **November 2019**

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, This saved me!!

Comment: It works but then every time you run `ef migrations add xxx`  or `ef migrations database update` you get a warning: "The EF Core tools version '3.0.0' is older than that of the runtime '3.1.0'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes."

Comment: @sports Since they have release `3.1.0` now you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this question and its answers: [Update .NET Core Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549046/update-net-core-tools)

It appears to be a known bug, as pointed out by an answer to that question: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/12963

The person who posted that question answered with a workaround they found. Maybe it will work for you as well.