# Azure Visual Studio publish Entity Framework migration error

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, entity-framework

I am trying to publish a website to Azure, but I am running into an error:

[image: the error]

I do not know how to solve it.

I tried to install it, but I get more errors:

[image: nuget install window]

I also tried `cmd` but still no luck.

[image: command prompt]

At this point I have no idea what to do now.

How can I fix this?

I am using this tutorial
[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL2y6AjSRss&list=PL5amK2cLXLjSnwJI5pYr6G_NaOvrN_dJP&index=1&t=551s&ab_channel=EvanGudmestad)

I'm trying to publish my website on Azure with database functionality

[image: another command]

Answer (score 0):

***To install Entity Framework 8.0, you need .NET SDK 8.0 version.***

Check the dotnet version by running the command `dotnet --info` in the Terminal.

```cs
C:\Users\username\>dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.100
 Commit:            57efcf1350
 Workload version:  8.0.100-manifests.71b9f198

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22621
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\

.NET workloads installed:
 Workload version: 8.0.100-manifests.71b9f198
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.0
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       5535e31a71

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.417 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

- To run the command `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`, install .NET 8.0 version.
- I could the command successfully.

[image]

If the issue still persists , navigate to `Visual Studio=>Tools=>Options=>Environment=>Preview features`=>Enable *Use previews of the .NET SDK(requires restart)*.

[image]

- Try running the command again.

I could publish the .NET Core web application with database to Azure even without installing `dotnet-ef`.

```
VS version: 17.8.3
.NET SDK version: 8.0.100
```

**Steps followed:**

- Cloned a sample .NET Core web application from [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-app-service-sqldb-dotnetcore).
- Created a publish profile to deploy the application to Azure App Service(Windows)
- Before publishing the profile, configure `service dependencies=>Connect`.

[image]

- Select `Azure SQL Database=>Select your SQL Database`

[image]

- Provide your *Database connection string name* and all other required details of your SQL server, click *Next=>Finish*:

[image]

- **Connection will be established:**

[image]

- **Settings of my publish profile:**

[image]

- **Able to publish the web application successfully:**

[image]

- **Running the deployed application:**

[image]

**Checking the Database with the commands:**

1. **Select  *  from [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]**

[image]

2. **Select  *  from [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]**

[image]

3. **Select  *  from [dbo].[Todo]**

[image]

**References:**

- [ASP.NET app with Azure SQL Database - Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase)
- You can also try the solution provided in the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870460/when-publishing-my-asp-net-core-mvc-app-the-entity-framework-migrations-option) regarding the same issue.