# Error when try to publish my ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to publish my ASP.NET Core Web API to Azure.

I get this error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

I try to re-connect with my Azure portal app service, but it does not work.

I try to stop and restart my app, but it does not work

Comment: Could you kindly [check the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870460/when-publishing-my-asp-net-core-mvc-app-the-entity-framework-migrations-option) and follow the steps to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

To install dotnet ef and specify version 7.0.0, use the following command:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.0
```

This command globally installs the Entity Framework (EF) CLI tool and sets its version to 7.0.0.

Comment: I had run the command: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0.0`. 
I recieve the error message: Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.

Comment: you can uninstall it by dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef --global and then install it again.